# New terminal window (duplicate session) from Putty command line?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, terminal, putty

Being on `Windows` and accessing `Linux` via `Putty`, is it possible to spawn new terminal (`Putty`) window from the command line? I.e. to send something to Linux, while responding on which, it initiate new `Putty` window open?

Similar can be done by Putty menu `Duplicate session`, but I am interested with command line version.

Comment: How would you identify the session to "duplicate" on command-line?

Comment: If I knew I would not ask. I can't say Linux does not identify terminals it communicates with.

Comment: I know this is a comment on an ancient thread, but "Duplicate session" requires a login again, which I would like to avoid if it is possible.  Short of using an X-session/virtual desktop, is there a way for putty or another such client to "clone" an active session (not requiring re-login) without saving the username and password to putty's preferences/config?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Putty Settings > Window > Behavior, you can check one of the boxes to open the system menu on a certain keypress (I personally use ALT-Space).

With this setting in place, you can hit ALT-Space, then type the d key to Duplicate Session. This will allow you to open a new putty window without needing to touch the mouse.

It's not a command line tool, but I find it extremely useful.

Comment: +1 Very helpful, and actually much simpler/safer than implementing something that spawns putty sessions via a linux response, that has to be initiated by putty in the first place ^^

Comment: +1 Sweet... I didn't know it was necessary to select that option within PuTTY; it should really be the default. Alt-Space was actually the first thing I tried and I was shocked/irritated that it didn't do anything, because Alt-Space has ALWAYS been the Windows standard way of opening the system menu on any given window. To this day, the only way I know how to minimize a window from the keyboard is by hitting ALT-Space then 'n'. I use it all the time!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no straight forward way to issue a command on a Linux host through ssh that will instruct the windows host where the ssh connection originated to spawn a new putty instance.

The remote host knows about putty only that it is a terminal capable of running a certain shell. It's not supposed to know how to spawn a new terminal on the local client.

Conceivably, it is possible to throw together a script of sorts (or look for a windows netcat clone) that will listen for a "ping" and spawn a new Putty. The second part of this "system" would contact the windows script via TCP from the remote host.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to touch the GUI, the only thing I can think of is using a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`. This wouldn't give you another GUI window, but you could have multiple windows/panes inside of either.